# TSQL: How to improve performance of SP having recursive SP calls in Cursor(Will HINTS be helpful ?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am facing issue in optimizing an SP and need your suggestions.

Actually, I am working on legacy system wherein the SP is to Submit an Order and is using Cursor and inside that Cursor and another SP is being called. As we know Cursors are not a good choice, so i thought to rewrite the Master SP with set based approach. But in this process i have found that the inner SP is again calling three other SPs. And seems Cursor is unavoidable in this situation.

We have also tried using "With Recompile" hint but still not get the satisfactory result. Actually to process 200 records SP is taking 15 mins and hence we are trying to optimize it.

I have also noticed that when i tried to extract Actual Execution Plan just by running the SP with 50 records, the plan is not getting generated and SSMS gets crashed after 20-25 mins of run.

Most of my queries are UPDATE and INSERT statements and thinking if TABLE HINTS could help but i have never used it earlier.

Request you to please suggest any alternate methods like HINTS with which we can optimize our SP.

Please find below a blueprint of my SP for more clarity. Thanks in advance :)

```
Master_SP
BEGIN 

EXEC Inner_SP_Level1

END

Inner_SP_Level1
BEGIN 

EXEC Inner_SP_Level21
EXEC Inner_SP_Level22
EXEC Inner_SP_Level23

END

Inner_SP_Level22
BEGIN 

EXEC Inner_SP_Level221
EXEC Inner_SP_Level222

END
```

Comment: You have to work with performance on the inner SP's and with indexes on the tables they are using.

Comment: Ok @idstam I shall concentrate on inner SPs first keeping indexes into consideration and shall post the results. Thanks

Comment: A can avoid using recursive calls. SQL engine is not pretty good on doing this and have a [(low) limit for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181714(v=sql.110).aspx). Instead I can learn the BL and do it the right way from scratch (if that option is open). "With Recompile" is good against parameter sniffing but there are other ways to it without forcing a recompilation every time